# Этот парсер, берет название и время, но при запуске кода, ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://www.vremyanamaza.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/9851-mwl07")
html = BS(r.content,"html.parser")

for el in html.select('.item'):
    title = el.select(".prayerName")
    time = el.select(".prayerTime")

    print(title[0].text + "-" + time[0].text)
```

Comment: а проверить что в title и time что-то есть не судьба?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогично другому ответу, но с использованием `select_one`, вместо `select`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://www.vremyanamaza.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/9851-mwl07")
html = BS(r.content,"html.parser")

for el in html.select('.item'):
    title = el.select_one(".prayerName")
    time = el.select_one(".prayerTime")
    if not title or not time:
        continue

    print(title.text + "-" + time.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте проверку на пустой элемент:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://www.vremyanamaza.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/9851-mwl07")
html = BS(r.content,"html.parser")

for el in html.select('.item'):
    title = el.select(".prayerName")
    time = el.select(".prayerTime")
    if not title or not time:
      continue
    print(title[0].text + "-" + time[0].text)
```